# Need a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've got a street address like, for instance, "1234 West 23rd Street". I'd like to blow out just the first street number and put spaces in between each number, like this:  "1 2 3 4 West 23rd Street".

Using the simple expression like `"([0-9])"` and replacing it with `"$1 "` almost works, except I want it to stop after the first space and not match, per the above example, the "23" in "23rd" as well.

Comment: @MarceloCantos In the question it says "PHP preg_replace"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with `preg_replace` and the [pattern modifier 'e'](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), which:

> does normal substitution of backreferences in the replacement string, evaluates it as PHP code, and uses the result for replacing the search string

```
$str = '1234 West 23rd Street';
preg_replace('/^([[:digit:]]+)/e', "implode(' ', str_split('$1'))", $str);
// returns '1 2 3 4 West 23rd St'
```

Comment: Better than my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to have PHP help you out here, you can't do all this with Regex alone (Regex will not do conditions like this, it's not designed for it).

Match on this: `([0-9]+)\s`, and then with the result you get (maybe just use the first result if there are more than one), add the spaces that you want in between each character.

Comment: If you really think I can't do it all with regex alone, I already know how I can do it using a combination of preg_match, preg_replace, and a couple of different expressions... it's just a lot less elegant than what I had in mind. :)

Comment: Sometimes can doesn't mean should!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to only match first digits and nothing after the space. You can use the `^` character to match the start of the line. So your regex could look something like this:

```
^(\d+)
```

The `\d` matches any digit.